# How to remove permissions from Huawei Ads Kit

Tags: permissions, ads, huawei-mobile-services

we found there are many additional permissions(not used by our app) in the ad kit. Any one please let us know if they are able to be removed? Generally users are very sensitive to permissions, especially as they are not required for the app functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

If your app does not require any of the additional permissions, add the code similar to the following in the AndroidManifest.xml file to remove the permission:

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" tools:node="remove" />
    ...

</manifest>
```

For more information please refer this link of SDK Data Security
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-personal-data-0000001050066921#section8547110181017